# Cant export formatted file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to automate the exporting of a formatted text file based on a query.

I have created a saved export.

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim lFileName As Long
Dim strCurrentDate As String
Dim dtCurrentDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFullName As String
Dim strExportSpec As String
Dim strQueryName As String

strDir = "C:\Users\Owner\Google Drive\2021\Job Submittal\"

strCurrentDate = InputBox("Enter Week Date", "Enter Week Date")

lFileName = InputBox("Enter Week Number", "Enter Week Number")

strFileName = "qryUnEmployment_" & strCurrentDate & "_" & lFileName

strFullName = strDir & strFileName & ".txt"

strExportSpec = "ExportqryUnemployment"
strQueryName = "qryUnEmployment"


'Does not recognize spec
' DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, strExportSpec, strQueryName, strFullName, True
 
 DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , strQueryName, strFullName, True
 
End Sub
```

If I run the current code the file does export but with no formatting.
I have to have the formatting with the columns lined up

Comment: If I run the commented out DoCmd, I get the run-time error 3625 The text file specification does not exist.

Comment: Dang, I get the same error. Bizarre. Glad I've never needed this. Annoying. Did you web search topic, start with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/access-2010-error-the-text-file-specification-number-does-not-exist-you-cannot-import-export-or-link-using-the-specification-when-running-a-macro-0e72255a-9028-414d-5c79-1a2aeb0d37d8. I know it concerns macro execution but maybe VBA has related issue.

Comment: Yes, I have been researching this for 3-4 hours. I see importing address, The ones addressing exporting say to create a spec which I did and when I I get the error that the spec does not exist.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `acExportFixed` instead of `acExportDelim` for this use case?

Comment: I do want the output to be delim